# Connecting Different Domains in Apahce commons VFS

Tags: java, apache, vfs

I'm trying to connect a server in different domain(Both source and destination are WINDOWS). the connection fails. I sniff the traffic by wireshark and noticed that my program is always connecting with the credentials I logged by. 
My Code:

```
UserAuthenticator auth = new StaticUserAuthenticator(serverConf.getDomain(), serverConf.getUsername(), serverConf.getPassword());
DefaultFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserAuthenticator(opts, auth);
FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);
if (serverConf.getFileSystem() == ServerConf.FileSystem.WINDOWS) {
    filePath = "\\\\" + serverConf.getServerIP() + "\\" + serverConf.getFolder().replace(':', '$');
    log.debug("filePath: "+filePath);
} else if (serverConf.getFileSystem()==ServerConf.FileSystem.FTP) {
    filePath = "ftp://" + serverConf.getServerIP() + "/" + serverConf.getFolder().replace('\\', '/');
}
folder = VFS.getManager().resolveFile(filePath,opts);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question actually is?

Comment: What shall I do to force the authenticator to use provided credentials(serverConf.getUsername/serverConf.getPassword in the example) instead of the credentials I logged in with?